# Mass identification in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, mass, metric-tensor

I am doing an exercise where I'm asked to rewrite the Schwarzschild metric using the following coordinate redefinition $$
r=r'\left(1+\frac{M}{2r'} \right)^2.
$$

I know the metric, in these the new coordinates, would be the following (isotropic) one:$$
ds^2=-\left(\frac{1-M/2r}{1+M/2r} \right)^2 dt^2+(1+M/2r)^4 (dr^2+r^2d \Omega^2).
$$

Then I'm asked to take the limit $r\to \infty$ and identify $M$ with the mass of the black hole. Ok, the problem is that I'm asked to justify why this isotropic change of coordinates is necessary to do the mass identification, and that doing so in the original coordinates (as I have always seen) would be incorrect.

Can anybody explain to me why this is necessary?

Thank you!

Reference: see question $2$ of problem $4$ here: http://www.sissa.it/app/phdsection/pastexams/2011/App11.pdf

Comment: As a side note let me give you a small tip off : You will find "mass" mentioned nowhere in the Einstein Field Equations. On crafting the Schwarzchild metric, there comes a factor that we can identify with mass. Pretty cool...

Comment: How is this related to my question?

Comment: Because on solving the equations, we get a condition when without the redefinition, the mass term is not visible (that was the historical approach)

Comment: Btw, $r \to \infty$ does not give the mass of a black hole. It can be identified with the mass of a spherical isolated body.

Comment: What definition of mass are you using?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252044/2451 and links thetein.