# Why it is the mass instead of the mass distribution used in Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, mass-energy

Schwarzschild metric is given by (Carroll, chapter 5)
$$
ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)\mathrm{d}t^2+\left(1-\frac{2GM}{r}\right)^{-1}\mathrm{d}r^2+r^2d\Omega^2
$$
where $M$ is the total mass of **a gravitating body**. According to the text book, this can be derived from the Einstein equation in vacuum
$$
R_{\mu\nu}=0
$$
using the spherically symmetric condition.

My question is why there is the $M$, instead of a term which looks like $\int\rho(r)\ \mathrm{d}V$ or $\int T_{\mu\nu}(r)\ \mathrm{d}V'$ shows up in Schwarzschild metric? Isn't it the inverse square relation ($F\propto r^{-2}$) that makes it possible in Newtonian gravitation to treat spherically symmetric mass distribution as a mass point? So how does this come true here in GR? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related: [Why isn't total Energy used in Schwarzchild Metric instead of just mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/788607/2451)

Comment: In the [interior solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric) we use the distribution as well.

Comment: The parameter $M$ is set during derivation so that the Schwarzschild solution asymptotically has the same gravitational field as an isolated body.

Comment: Schwarzschild derived his metric while serving an an officer at the front during the first World War. Einstein had published his first paper on GR a few months earlier, and had been able to derive only an approximate solution. So Schwarzschild's solution would have been quite remarkable even if he had done the work in a more sheltered environment. I suggest we cut him some slack for having simplified somewhat.

Comment: M is the integral of density. So you are right, and yes it is used and the solution is only valid outside of the mass

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)) tells us that:

> any spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum field equations must be static and asymptotically flat. This means that the exterior solution (i.e. the spacetime outside of a spherical, nonrotating, gravitating body) must be given by the Schwarzschild metric.

So that means that the variation of density with radial distance is irrelevant. As long as we are outside the body all we need to know is the total mass.

If we are inside the body then the variation of density with distance does matter, and in that case the geometry is given by the Schwarzschild interior metric not the Schwarzschild metric.

Comment: obviously this is basically correct but I wondered whether one should qualify the use of the term "static" since the metric is only static in the outer region here.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why there is the M, instead of a term which looks like ∫ρ(r) dV or ∫Tμν(r) dV′ shows up in Schwarzschild metric?

The Schwarzschild metric describes only the part of spacetime without matter and must continuously connect to metric of the interior part with matter.

Denoting energy density of matter $\varepsilon$ and $\kappa$ Einstein's gravitation constant the corresponding solution for metric component $g^{-1}_{rr}$ reads

\begin{equation} 
\label{e-2lambda}
g^{-1}_{rr} =\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 1-{\displaystyle \frac{\kappa}{r}\int_{0}^{r}\varepsilon(\tilde{r})~\tilde{r}^2~d\tilde{r}}, & ~~~~\mbox{for} & 0\leq r \leq R
\\
\\1-{\displaystyle \frac{\kappa}{r}\int_{0}^{R}\varepsilon(\tilde{r})~\tilde{r}^2~d\tilde{r}} & ~~~~ \mbox{for} & R\lt r \lt \infty. \end{array}\right.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

For matter like for example perfect fluid energy density is proportional to the rest mass density. It yields $\varepsilon=\rho~c^2$. In this case the constant in vacuum part of solution $(r>R) $ can be expressed by the total rest mass $M$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{8 \pi G}{c^4} \int_{0}^{R} c^2~\rho(\tilde{r})~\tilde{r}^2~ d\tilde{r}= \frac{2 G}{c^2} \int_{0}^{V_{R}} \rho(\tilde{r})~ dV = \frac{2 G M}{c^2}\equiv r_{S} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where are $dV= 4 \pi~\tilde{r}^2~ d\tilde{r}$ and $ V_{R}=4/3 \pi~R^3$