# Can someone explain intuitively why "black rings" are possible in 4+1 dimensional gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime-dimensions

In 3+1 dimensional general relativity, all black holes must be topologically equivalent to a sphere.
However in 4+1 dimensional gravity, this isn't the case, there Torus shaped black holes are possible.
Can someone explain intuitively why "black rings" are possible in 4+1 dimensional gravity?
I think I get my it's possible, any my explanation is dues to the fact that in 4+1 dimensional gravity, the event horizon should be proportional to the Square root of the mass, but I'm not sure how accurate I am.

Comment: I give an intuitive argument in my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/763666/2451).

Comment: It doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Consider to elaborate why.

Comment: I want to know why they are possible in 4+1d, and the explanation there, doesn't really help me.