# Does gravity exist in two spatial dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime-dimensions, anyons

I've been studying [anyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon) and was wondering if gravity exists in two spatial dimensions and how it affects these particles?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200020/2451 and links therein.

Comment: In the paper "General relativity in two- and three-dimensional space-times"(https://www.csun.edu/~vcphy00d/PDFPublications/1977%20GR(2+1).pdf) Peter Collas shows that two-dimensional space-time can have arbitrary curvature but not matter. The three-dimensional space-time is more interesting. The empty space is always flat and therefore matter there cannot interact with each other gravitationally. Later he investigates spherically symmetric metrics and presents some interesting solutions. Maybe it helps to answer your question.

Comment: Gravity in 2+1 is a topological theory, meaning that there is no local curvature. However some interesting solution is given by considering the inclusion of the cosmological constant (see BTZ black hole).

Comment: Thanks. I will look at that