# Significance of Poles of Correlation Function in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, correlation-functions

In QFT, specifically in scattering processes, what is the physical significance of the poles / residues of the $N$-point correlation function? And why?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29532/2451

Answer (score 4):

In the frequency domain, poles of the correlation function $G^{r}(\omega)$ correspond to resonance frequencies. In many body theory, such resonances describe metastable oscillations relating to quasi-particles characterized by self-energies.